# Instanciar metodo dinamico

Tags: php

Tenho várias classes, pra não ficar setando método por método criei uma classe com todos os métodos instanciados, sendo assim só seto o método, queria saber se funciona.

**Instancias.class.php**

```
class Instancias {
   public $Header;

   public function GetInstancias () {
      $this->Header = new Header;
   }
}
```

**Header.class.php**

```
class Header {
   public function GetHeader () {
      echo "Header";
   }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require "Instancias.class.php";
require "Header.class.php";
$Instancias = new Instancias;
$Instancias->GetInstancias ();
$this->GetHeader ();
```

Comment: Se não quer ficar instanciando é um indício que não precisa de classes, né?

Comment: @Maneiro mais e indicado fazer desse jeito?

Comment: Eu acho que não, mas as pessoas andam fazendo cada maluquice em PHP que eu nem sei mais nada, o maluco virou normal :D

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Tente usar o Trait pra estender funcionalidades comuns para várias classes como getter and setter sem precisar instanciar-las de outras classes. Apenas importe o arquivo do trait na classe que vc quer implementar e utilize o operador "use" para habilita-lo;

O seu arquivo de chamada index.php não tá fazendo muito sentido.

Veja o código abaixo:

**Classe teste.php**

```
require_once "GetterAndSetterTrait.php";

class teste
{
    use GetterAndSetterTrait;

    private $atributo;  
}
```

**Trait GetterAndSetterTrait.php**

```
Trait GetterAndSetterTrait
{
    public function __call($func, $value)
    {
        $attrb = strtolower(substr($func,3));
        $func = strtolower(substr($func,0,3));       

        switch ($func) {
            case 'set':
                $this->$attrb = $value[0];
                break;
            case 'get':
                return $this->$attrb;
                break;
            default:
                throw New \Exception('variável '.$attrb.' não existe!');
                break;
        } 
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once "teste.php";

$a = New teste();

$a->setAtributo("Atributo Configurado com Sucesso");
echo $a->getAtributo(); //Atributo Configurado com Sucesso
```